# Upgrading 13.04 to 13.10 compatibility

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, compatibility

I have an AMD CPU with radeon graphics card tower. When I tried to install 12.04 and 13.10 using burned disc I had problems with the graphics from the installation phase. 13.04 installed without problems and after the installation I downloaded the catalyst software which improved performance. I was wondering if upgrading to 13.10 using the notification popup that appears at startup is going to mess up the drivers again, or it should be safe?

Answer (score 1):

I had an **AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics Card** with proprietary driver working well under **Ubuntu 13.04** and I experienced a number of problems while upgrading to 13.10, and finally managed to get it done a couple of weeks ago.

I don't know much about the cause(s) of upgrading problems (which I never had before in years with Ubuntu) I experienced and how they disappeared as I took the precaution of disabling the proprietary AMD driver and switching to much more trouble-free Intel driver before upgrade on both occasions.

But my experience shows that it's very handy to **use Clonezilla to backup your Ubuntu partition** so that **you can always *go back in time* in case of a disaster ;-)**

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way is to check!**

1. Get the Ubuntu 13.10 ISO.
2. Get your hands on a USB drive or a Cd/DVD.
3. Create an bootable USB/CD/DVD using **unetbootin** or **multibootusb** or any of your favorite software.
4. Boot the device and check if everything goes well.
5. If everything is fine, upgrade.

> If you want to save some data, you can use the iso to do an *in-place-upgrade*. Just select install-->update existing OS.

**The easier way is to upgrade!(blind dive in)**

**You can even ask someone with same/similar configuration using Ubuntu 13.10**